# Can vscode extensions add floating buttons within a text editor? (Similar to "Add Configuration..." in launch.json editors.)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When you open a launch.json file in vscode you see a prominent "Add Configuration..." button in the lower right hand corner of the text editor.

Can my extension create such a button (only for files of a specific language)?

The closest I have managed is to get is by creating a CodeLensProvider that provides a CodeLens at Range(0, 0, 0, 0). This only gets me a small link at the top of the document though and it is easy for the user to miss.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Add a feature request to make this part of the vscode API